# Add an OnClick handler with jQuery only once - even if called again

Tags: jquery

If I assign a handler to the OnClick event of an element twice, the handler will be executed twice.  But I want to change this so even if I assign it twice, the handler will only execute one time.

Nonsensical example to demonstrate issue:

```
$('.button').click(
    function(){
       alert('here');
});
$('.button').click(
    function(){
       alert('here');
});
```

So I've added the handler twice.  Now when I click an element with that class, I'd get two alert boxes.

The question is, how do I restrict it so I would only get one alert box?

Comment: Why would you need to add the event twice?

Comment: There is a function executed on this page every time there is a postback, in order to add the handler to dynamically created elements.  However any element which previously existed now has the handler twice...

Comment: I think you need to rethink your approach to avoid binding twice, but if you're in a crunch, I suppose you could use `$('.button').off('click').on('click', function(){...});` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/SsRxv/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If `.one()` is in fact what you're after (removing the event handler after it has been triggered once) then I believe that's the correct answer. If not, you can unbind the event before binding it:

```
var myEventHandler = function () {alert('hello')};
$('a').unbind('click', myEventHandler);
$('a').bind('click', myEventHandler);
```

Should work.

Edit: since this reply keeps getting up votes, I'll add another (better in most cases) solution that will work at least in the OP's case. When dealing with dynamically added content simply use jQuery's `on()` on a parent element instead of applying the event handler directly on the element.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 6):

You can also remove any existing click events in the function with function off('click'):

```
$('.button').off('click').click(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: the best answer

Answer (score 5):

To have the events triggered only once, bind them only once. When dynamically adding elements, bind the event handler to the parent element using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUG2d/):

```
<div id="container">
 <p>Paragraph #1</p>
</div>

<div>
 <button id="add">Add Elements</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 var n = 1;
 $('#add').click(function() {
   $('#container').append('<p>Paragraph #' + ++n + '</p>');
 });
 $('#container').on('click', 'P', function() {
   alert($(this).text());
 });
</script>
```

Note how the event handlers are registered with `on()` only once. The code that dynamically adds elements does not register the event handlers.

Answer (score 5):

a little trick that can help:

```
jQuery(".button:not(.clickadded)").click(function(){

     alert('here');

).addClass("clickadded");
```

Answer (score 4):

Use one.
http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$( ".button" ).one( 'click', function(){
    alert( '....' )
});
```

Comment: Note this will cause the `alert()` to show for one click only and ignore subsequent clicks. The OP's problem is that the `alert()` is showing more than once per click.

Comment: powerbuoy has the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method I'm using, similar to Miquel's method in some ways.

```
$.prototype.once = function() {
    var ret = this.not(function() {
        return this.once;
    });
    this.each(function(id, el) {
        el.once = true;
    });
    return ret;
};
```

Use it like this,

```
$('#footer')
    .once()
    .click(function(){
        console.log('click the footer');
    });
```

Once also supports a parameter so you can have different types

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by a flag, I know it is not the best by just an idea

```
if (!alreadyBound) {
     $('.button').bind('click', submitEvtHandler);
     alreadyBound = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no point to add function twice. However if you have to then you can do add `return false` to one of the function.

```
$('.button').click(
    function(){
       return false;
       alert('here');
});
$('.button').click(
    function(){
       alert('here');
});​
```